# After fetching a value from DB then assign it to a variable, then i can't use it to the next query

Tags: php, codeigniter

This is my model:

```
 public function GetStudentData() 
 {
     $sID = $this->input->get('id');
     $class_id = $this->db->query("SELECT student.class_id FROM student WHERE student.sID = '$sID'");   
     $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM student WHERE(sID='$id'AND class_id = '$class_id')");
     if($query->num_rows() > 0)
     {
         return $query->row();
     }else{
         return false;
     } 
 }
```

How can I use `$class_id` in the next query?

Comment: What is your actual issue? Do you have error messages, what debugging have you done yourself, how have you tried to fix it, etc, etc?

Comment: You are missing the step where you grab the row from the first query, and extract the actual class_id. Your `$class_id` variable doesn't hold what you think it does.

Answer (score 0):

you could do it in one query...  (from your example [SIC])

```
    public function GetCSData() {
    $id = $this->input->get('id');      
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT student.* 
                               FROM student 
                               WHERE student.sID = '$id' 
                               AND student.class_id = (SELECT class_id 
                                                       FROM student 
                                                       WHERE student.sID = '$id')");
    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        return $query->row();
    }else{
        return false;
    }         

}//..GetCSData end
```

looking at it though, that will give the same result as

```
SELECT *
FROM student 
WHERE sID = '$id'
```

maybe I am missing a point?

Comment: Thank you very much. I hope i will get more help from you.